# mongoDB: Update nested array object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like the nested object with the id `BAHx9KeKjuMePce6f` to be updated:

```
{
    "_id" : "sgG6G9XTvvjj7uxwQ",
    "target" : [
        {
            "title" : "content",
            "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM"
        },
        {
            "title" : "content",
            "id" : "BAHx9KeKjuMePce6f" <--
        }
    ]
}
```

So this is what I tried:

```
var newData = { title: "new", one: "more", id: 'BAHx9KeKjuMePce6f' };

Collection.update(
    { _id: 'sgG6G9XTvvjj7uxwQ', 'target.id': 'BAHx9KeKjuMePce6f' }, 
    { $set: newData }
);
```

The result should be:

```
{
    "_id" : "sgG6G9XTvvjj7uxwQ",
    "target" : [
        {
            "title" : "content",
            "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM"
        },
        {
            "title": "new", 
            "one": "more",
            "id" : "BAHx9KeKjuMePce6f"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update specific element in array you can use mongodb [positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Try the following query:

```
var newData = { title: "new", one: "more", id: 'BAHx9KeKjuMePce6f' };

Collection.update(
    { _id: 'sgG6G9XTvvjj7uxwQ', 'target.id': 'BAHx9KeKjuMePce6f' }, 
    { $set: { 'target.$': newData } }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the use the positional parameter `$` to indicate you want to update the array element, rather than the root of the document, see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/positional/):

```
Collection.update({
  _id: 'sgG6G9XTvvjj7uxwQ',
  'target.id': 'BAHx9KeKjuMePce6f'
}, {
  $set: {
    "target.$": newData
  }
});
```