# update nested object in array Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like the nested object with the id `5f0e14241f5ccb42d8742767` to be updated:

```
 {
        "_id": "5f0b33ab52a4e966c754d963",
        "make": "Toyota",
        "model": "Prius",
        "engine": "1.8",
        "insurances": [
            {
                "yearlyPremium": {
                    "$numberDecimal": "60.39"
                },
                "_id": "5f0e14241f5ccb42d8742767",
                "startDate": "1970-01-19T09:31:15.550Z",
                "monthlyPremium": {
                    "$numberDecimal": "5.49"
                },
                "excess": 100
            },
            {
                "yearlyPremium": {
                    "$numberDecimal": "71.39"
                },
                "_id": "5f0e147c0340243eb03b5247",
                "startDate": "1970-01-19T09:31:15.550Z",
                "monthlyPremium": {
                    "$numberDecimal": "6.49"
                },
                "excess": 100
            },
       ]
 }
```

So in my PATCH rest api request, I just want to change the monthly premium, from what it is currently `5.49` to `1.50`. Hence I pass the `carId: 5f0b33ab52a4e966c754d963` and the particular `inusranceId: 5f0e14241f5ccb42d8742767` (nested in Car object) as query params, to identify which insurance in the insurances array needs updating. Then in the request body I pass the item to be modified (`monthlyPremium`):

[image]

I followed the stack overflow solution: [mongoDB: Update nested array object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990071/mongodb-update-nested-array-object)

So this is what I tried:

```
router.route('/insurance')
.patch(async (req, res) => {
    const { carId, insuranceId } = req.query
    const { startDate, monthlyPremium, excess } = req.body
    try {
        const foundCar = await Car.findById(carId)
        const foundCar = foundCar.insurances.filter(ins => {
            return ins._id == insuranceId
        })
        
        foundInsurance.startDate = startDate && new Date(startDate * 1000) || foundInsurance.startDate,
        foundInsurance.monthlyPremium = monthlyPremium && parseFloat(monthlyPremium) || foundInsurance.monthlyPremium,
        foundInsurance.yearlyPremium = monthlyPremium && parseFloat(monthlyPremium) * 12 || foundInsurance.yearlyPremium,
        foundInsurance.excess = excess && Number(excess) || foundInsurance.excess
        
        Car.update(
            {_id: carId, "insurances._id": insuranceId}, 
            {$set: {"insurances.$":foundInsurance}}
        )

        res.send(`Insurance updated`)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: err })
    }
})
```

The request queries are captured correctly in the code. The request succeeds and returns `Insurance updated`, but nothing gets updated. Everything is working except the update method is not updating the info `monthlyPremium` to `1.50`.

**UPDATE**

@Mahan, I tried your suggested approach, unfortunately the record still hasn't changed. Printing `foundInsurance` I get this (it doesn't print the values in the console, just the meta data):

```
found insurance: {
  yearlyPremium: Decimal128 {
    _bsontype: 'Decimal128',
    bytes: <Buffer 97 17 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3c 30>
  },
  _id: 5f0e14241f5ccb42d8742767,
  startDate: 1970-01-19T09:31:15.550Z,
  monthlyPremium: Decimal128 {
    _bsontype: 'Decimal128',
    bytes: <Buffer 25 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3c 30>
  },
  excess: 100
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using mongoose `arrayFilters` like this:

```js
Car.update(
  { _id: carId }, 
  { $set: { "insurances.$[elem]": foundInsurance } },
  { arrayFilters: [ { 'elem._id': insuranceId } ] }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mahan. Actually now I'm getting an error on POSTMAN for that endpoint. `{
    "error": {
        "stringValue": "\"insurance\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": "insurance",
        "path": "_id",
        "reason": {}
    }
}`    Not sure why. It's the same setup you see in the screenshot in my question for POSTMAN

Comment: Would you please post your `foundInsurance`  object ? After you set its properties.

Comment: Ok the problem right now is with the PATCH endpoint. Even if I empty the whole body of the call back (for the API) from any code, I'm still getting this error. So there must be an issue with the endpoint. I can't see where the issue is!!!

Comment: Do you set `app.use(bodyParser.json());` middleware in your express app.js ?

Comment: And also `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));`

Comment: Ok I fixed that error by changing PATCH to PUT. Now the request is responding successfully. Not really sure why. In answer to you question, I use: `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: I'm not sure if those middleware are needed. I'm able to console.log the `monthlyPremium` value from the request body in my code. So in my code `const { startDate, monthlyPremium, excess } = req.body` then I console log monthPremiuim 
    `console.log('monthly Premium: ${monthlyPremium}')`  I'm able to see the value from the request body logged in the console: `monthly Premium: 1.5`

Comment: Yes the Rest API is showing as success in POSTMAN, but it's not updating the record

Comment: Where do you define `foundInsurance` variable. I think you first have to define it like `let foundInsurane = {}` then assign its properties.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. The `foundInsurance.monthlyPremiuim` is assigned the new value successfully. I console logged it: `console.log('monthly premium: ${foundInsurance.monthlyPremium}')`. In the console I get the new value: `monthly premium: 1.5`. The problem is the `update` is not working

Comment: Do you want to connect to my laptop and see? I won't give you control. Just for you to see it from a better view

Comment: Okay, what platform do you use ?

Comment: We can use skype and you screen share with me. Here is my skype id `live:d76a5712c5ab3661`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942037/mongoose-findoneandupdate-does-not-update-an-existing-field